# Capybara Acceptance DSL with MiniTest::Spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, dsl, minitest

The readme for Capybara (see [Using Capybara with MiniTest::Spec](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara)) says that I can do this if I include the module correctly, but it doesn't give any illustrative examples of how... I've tried including the module like this:

```
class MiniTest::Spec
  include Capybara::DSL
end
```

... to no avail. I keep getting this error:

> `<main>': undefined method`feature' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

How can I get it to work as it's written in the commented-out code?

---

**spec/acceptance/api/reward_terms_spec.rb:**

```
require "#{Dir.pwd}/spec/acceptance/acceptance_helper"

# this syntax works...

describe 'reward terms acceptance test' do
  include Capybara::DSL

  describe '#index' do
    specify {
      visit '/reward_terms'
      # ...
    }
  end
end

# this syntax doesn't work...

# feature 'RewardTerms', %q{
#   In order to get all reward terms available to me
#   As an API client
#   I want to list all active RewardTerms
# } do

#   background do
#     set_api_headers
#   end

#   scenario 'RewardTerm index' do
#     visit '/reward_terms'
#     ...
#   end
# end
```

**spec/acceptance/acceptance_helper.rb:**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require "#{Dir.pwd}/config/environment"

require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'capybara/rails'

def set_api_headers(device_id = 'abcd1234')
  header 'Accept', 'application/json'
  header 'X-Device-Id', device_id
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice description in [this post](http://code-ningja.posterous.com/73460416) for how you should make MinitTest::Spec run with capybara. There he basically includes the Capybara::DSL into the base class of all the specs as in

```
class RequestSpec < MiniTest::Spec
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include Capybara::DSL
end
```

this works rather nicely in our setup, but of course it does not reopen the MiniTest::Spec.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that post, but that only allows you to use the Capybara matchers, not the BDD DSL for acceptance testing, which is what I'm after...

Comment: On [link](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) the part on the Capybara DSL is contained int the section on "Using Capybara with RSpec", there it says  "Finally, Capybara also comes with a built in DSL for creating descriptive acceptance tests:". However after presenting the DSL in action it says: "`feature` is in fact just an alias for `describe ..., :type => :request`, `background` is an alias for `before`, and `scenario` for `it`." So you are out of luck if you want to use it with MiniTest as it is an RSpec-only feature, but you might try to define your own aliases

Comment: The linked blog post has been taken down from Posterous, but here it is in the Internet Archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20130314201201/http://code-ningja.posterous.com/73460416

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple test_helper rig to run functional & integration tests in Rails using spec syntax. Based on a gist by [tenderlove](https://github.com/tenderlove), the [article mentioned above re: MiniTest with Capybara](http://code-ningja.posterous.com/73460416), as well as a lot of tinkering & source-poring.

https://gist.github.com/1607879

Answer (score 0):

You should add `minitest-rails-capybara` gem to the `Gemfile` and add a word "feature" to the end of description as follows:

```
feature 'RewardTerms feature', %q{
   In order to get all reward terms available to me
   As an API client
   I want to list all active RewardTerms
} do

  background do
    set_api_headers
  end

  scenario 'RewardTerm index' do
    visit '/reward_terms'
    #...
  end
end
```

The special word "feature" is case incensitive, and can be "browser". You can customize it by adding a line to the `test_helper.rb`:

```
MiniTest::Spec.register_spec_type(/FooBar\z/i, Capybara::Rails::TestCase)
```